# How to recover bluetooth packet loss?? Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, packet, recovery, loss

I'm currently creating an Android App where it collects data through bluetooth and draw a real time graph but it seems like after short while there is packet loss and graph comes out weird. I've been searching for a while how to recover the loss but seems like there is no way.... only TCP/IP or UDP has.... Since I need all the data, I can't ignore the packets that doesn't have starting bit or end bit. Is there anyway to prevent the loss or recover the loss completely?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use of RFComm on Android already has built in [packet order and reliability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_protocols#Radio_frequency_communication_.28RFCOMM.29) like TCP. You should try running tests to see if the Android device is too far away, receiving accurate information, has a bad Bluetooth module, or if the sensor is at fault.